# No data is read in SqlReader Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Tags: asp.net, sql, handler, sqldatareader

I know this problem has been posted millions of times before, but this might be different.

I am using a sql table with columns id,year,month,pdffile

in my webpage, I would like the user to view the pdf document that they would like to see from what time frame they choose.

so far with this:

```
string year = ddlYear.SelectedValue.ToString();    
string month = ddlMonth.SelectedValue.ToString();
pdfFrame.Attributes["src"] = "../pdfDocs.ashx?Year=" + year + "&Month=" + month;
```

it loads the pdf, if it is there. that is my problem.
how would I catch the error in my question title? I want to catch that error and display a message in a label to the user saying that no file was found. I am using a handler to read the varbinary that is my pdf file.

Here is the handler code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=DEV6\MSSQLHOSTING;Database=Intranet;Trusted_Connection=True;");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select PDFDocument from LeaveChart where (Year like @Year and Month like @Month)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Year", context.Request.QueryString["Year"]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Month", context.Request.QueryString["Month"]);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

reader.Read();

byte[] content = (byte[])reader.GetValue(0);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(content);
ms.Position = 0;
context.Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
context.Response.End();
reader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

like I said, that works to display present files. can anyone offer some suggestions?
is it possible to send a message from the handler back to the web page saying no file and how to display it without shocking the customer?

thanks in advance

Comment: And I guess return type of your handler is MemoryStream?

Comment: if(!reader.Read()) ShowNoFile(); ?

Comment: yes. the return type is memory stream @PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the signature of your Handler, then:

```
public bool <YourHandlerName>(out MemoryStream ms)
{
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=DEV6\MSSQLHOSTING;Database=Intranet;Trusted_Connection=True;");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select PDFDocument from LeaveChart where (Year like  @Year and Month like @Month)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Year", context.Request.QueryString["Year"]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Month", context.Request.QueryString["Month"]);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
ms = new MemoryStream(content);
if(reader.HasRows)
 {
  byte[] content = (byte[])reader.GetValue(0);
  ms.Position = 0;
  context.Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
  ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
  context.Response.End();
  reader.Close();
  conn.Close();
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

I guess I got your question correctly.

Comment: if I took this verbatim, I would get errors regarding the memory stream. telling me that it would give a different meaning to ms which is used in a parent or current scope.

Comment: Another way could be changing the signature and returning the memory stream.like: **public bool <YourHandlerName>(out MemoryStream ms)** to **public MemoryStream <HandlerName>(out bool fileFound)** and then set the fileFound accordingly. MemoryStream will be empty if file not found.